# can't browse on wifi (wlan0)

Tags: wireless, networking, android

At this moment I'm in hospital and I'm trying to use the Wi-fi network that is available for the patients. Even if I'm connect to the network and the signal strength is excellent I can't browse on the internet.

On the other hand, if I join from an android phone, I can browse on the internet without any problems (and the speed is good too).

I don't think that my computer network has any problem, bc I  was using with without any problem from my home wifi network

What might be the problem?

This is what I get from `ifconfig->wlan0`:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:d5:3d:5c:b4:13  
          inet addr:192.168.1.63  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e6d5:3dff:fe5c:b413/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:30591
          TX packets:2365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:600017 (600.0 KB)  TX bytes:262019 (262.0 KB)
          Interrupt:17
```

all I get from `ping 192.168.1.1` is:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.58 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.58 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.58 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
```

the `iwconfig` response is

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"HOSPRFR"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:DF:A3:B2   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

and the `route -n` output is

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.68.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

and finally, the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: When you access the wifi through your phone, are you redirected to a login page on your phones browser maybe? Many "open" networks I've seen work like that. You connect to the wifi, open a browser, it redirects you to a login page where you have to agree to their terms of service and maybe input some information about yourself and then you can use the internet. So if there is indeed this browser redirect going on you could try to copy the url from your phone and input in firefox on your laptop

Comment: try using google dns 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 if you set either one of these through network manager, you will have to reconnect to the network for the changes to take effect

Comment: output of `ifconfig`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` & if possible `route -n` please!

Comment: @AzkerM: I've added the outputs of `ifconfig` and `ping`

Comment: @Daniel no, there is no webpage. I just specify the network password

Comment: @mchid it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Many thx for all the feedback, but try to make t as an answer in order to vote or select it as solution

Comment: @rda I don't see the output for `cat /etc/resolv.conf` as I've requested. Anyhow, was your issue sorted out??

Comment: @AzkerM No, I didn't solve the problem yet. Any ideas? I've added the output of `resolv.conf`

Comment: @rda your nameserver on the `resolv.conf` file seems unusual. Can you do `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` & change only the `127.0.1.1` to `8.8.8.8`. Once done, just browse and have a look. Just to see whether this causing because of the DNS.

Comment: same problem. can't browse :(

Comment: make sure ports 53 67 and 68 are open, although if you can connect to wifi router with no prob then that's prob not it but you should still check. Port 53 is DNS and 67/68 are for DHCP.

Comment: BTW, isn't the nameserver usually 127.0.0.1